# When finding the limit of a composite function, do you find the limit of the interior function and then the exterior function?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am working through Khan Academy's calculus course and got stuck when the limits of composite functions came up.  Say we want to find the limit of $f(g(x))$ as $x$ approaches one.  The notation says that you plug $x$ into $g(x)$ and then plug $g(x)$ into $f$.  Hence $f(g(x))$.  But that doesn't find the limit at $1$.  To be honest, I don't even know what the goal is with finding limits of composite functions.  Are we trying to find the limit of $f$ or $g$? or both?  If both, what does the limit of both mean in physical terms? Is it the rate of flow in a water pipe? The notation is unclear and makes the problem seem undefined to me.  I would appreciate another explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  You are supposed to find the limit of the interior function and then use that limit as the x value for the exterior function while taking the limit of the exterior function.  I was confused because the notation is wrong.  Should have a lim in front of both g and f.

Comment: This is NOT correct. Let $\;f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if} & x = 9\\
2 & \text{if} & x \neq 9\\ \end{cases}\;$ and $\;g(x) = x^2,\;$ and consider $\;\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3}f(g(x)).\;$ As $x$ gets closer and closer to $3$ *without being equal to* $3$ (the part about $x \neq 3$ when taking the limit ACTUALLY MATTERS in this example), the values of $g(x)$ are NOT equal to $9,$ and hence the values of $f(g(x))$ will (always) be $f(\neq 9) = 2.$ Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3}f(g(x)) = 2,$ which is NOT equal to $f\left(\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3} g(x)\right) = f(9) = 1.$

Comment: That's not what I said, there should be two limits.  One in front of each function. I didn't clarify that until the end of my post which I will do now.

Comment: *Say we want to find the limit of* $f(g(x))$ *as* $x$ *approaches one* --- This is a limit of the SINGLE function $f(g(x)),$ although this function is EXPRESSED as a composition of two other functions. For example, if I were to ask you to subtract $5 \cdot 6$ from $40,$ the result would be $10,$ because $5 \cdot 6$ and $30$ are different names for the SAME number, despite the fact that two numbers are involved in the name $5 \cdot 6.$ Thus, another way to state the limit question is to say: "Let $h(x)$ be the function $f(g(x)).$ What is the limit of $h(x)$ as $x$ approaches one?"

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm just not articulating my thoughts correctly.  I have gotten every single problem regarding limits of composite functions correct since I posted this post.  I'm not versed enough in math notation to express what I'm trying to say in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Oversimplifying the situation, if you're trying to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(g(x))$, you're asking "what happens if I plug values of $x$ close to (but not equal to 1) into $f(g(x))$?" That is, if you plug them into $g$ and then plug the results into $f$.

If $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} g(x) = L$, that means that plugging in values of $x$ close to 1 into $g(x)$ gives you values close to $L$. You can then determine what happens if you plug these values into $f$ by taking $\lim\limits_{x \to L} f(x)$.

Comment: So do I plug x into g and then into f and find the limit of that? Or do I find the limit of g(x) and plug the limit of g(x) into f(x)?

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are nice and fluffy, that is they are continuous and all that jazz, then
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=g\left(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\right)$$